# "Failed to retrieve application ABI from Android.mk" error in ndk-gdb

Tags: android, ndk-gdb

I'm trying to debug a native android app using ndk-gdb tool. When I execute the ndk-gdb, I get the following error.

> "/home/amila/Android/Ndk/android-ndk-r20/build/core/add-application.mk:88:
>   *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop. ERROR: Failed to retrieve application ABI from Android.mk."

I have built the native parts using `ndk-build` command and the app is getting built in Android Studio without any issue.

jni directory: /ndktest/jni (where ndktest is the app name)

I ran the `ndk-gdb` command in the directory where the AndroidManifest.xml resides (/ndktest/app/src/main).

I also tried by adding `APP_ABI := arm64-v8a` into the Android.mk and nothing changed.

### jni/Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)    

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := ndktest
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ndktest.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

### jni/Application.mk

```
APP_ABI := arm64-v8a
```

There should be no errors when I run the `ndk-gdb` tool.

Answer (score 0):

Note that ndk-gdb does not take your gradle configuration into consideration, so if you have a modified file structure, make sure that your Android.mk file is located inside a "jni" folder inside the project directory.